# Urllib caching image unwantedly?

Tags: python, image, caching, download, urllib

I am writing a simple script that is supposed to download N random images from Unsplash. It works-- but only *mostly*. It always downloads N of the same images. I believe `urllib` is caching the image, but even after trying `urllib.urlcleanup()` it still downloads the same N images. Can you please help me? Here is my code:

```
import urllib

num = 4
for i in range(1, num + 1):
    print("Downloading image #" + str(i) + "...")
    urllib.urlretrieve("https://source.unsplash.com/random", "image" + str(i) + ".jpg")
    urllib.urlcleanup()
```

EDIT: Some people pointed out that I was getting the 404 page. Yes, I was, but after I just fixed *that* problem the main problem is still occurring.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the images you actually get. They are all the same because this appears to be the Unsplash 404 page, indicating that Unsplash doesn't recognise it as identifying an image. The URL you are using for random images is probably incorrect.

You may find [this page on downloading random images](https://sheelahb.com/blog/unsplash-random-image-how-to/) helpful.

Comment: You are right, but I am still having the problem I mentioned.

Comment: Did you read the article I pointed you to? The URLs you use should be of the form `https://source.unsplash.com/collection/CCCCC/N`, where CCCCCC is the collection number and N is the number of some article. If you want to select across the whole site you will have to randomise the collection too, and take precautions not to exceed the collection size.

Comment: Actually, yes. Thank you. I have created this: `urllib.urlretrieve("https://source.unsplash.com/collection/466697/" + str(i), os.path.join("images", "image" + str(i) + ".jpg"))`

Comment: Yes, I found by experimentation that the URL cacheing did indeed defeat the randomness, in the browser. You can, however, get different images from the whole site by asking for `https://source.unsplash.com/random/1`, `.../random/2` and so on, which allows you to pull from all collections.

Answer (score 1):

replace

```
urllib.urlretrieve("https://source.unsplash.com/random" + str(i), "image" + str(i) + ".jpg")
```

with

```
urllib.urlretrieve("https://source.unsplash.com/random", "image" + str(i) + ".jpg")
```

Comment: Just like holdenweb, you are right, but I am still having the problem I mentioned.

Comment: I tried your script. It is downloading different images each time for me.